# GitHub Pages of repository not displaying correctly

Tags: vue.js, github-pages

My [Startpage](https://github.com/ll931217/startpage) is a GitHub page, it is linked to [here](https://ll931217.github.io/startpage/). As you can see when going to that link, the website is very much "broken". It is using the navbar of my [portfolio](https://ll931217.github.io/) page (Don't judge, its an old design) for some reason is it showing the navbar when I didn't package it on my  startpage. My startpage supposed to look like this:

[image: My startpage]

I tried to "rebundle" and push it to my `gh-pages` branch but nothing changed. You can check my source code in the `master` branch. When I deleted my portfolio repo, it didn't have any effect.

Comment: Your gh-pages branch does not has a src folder.

Comment: @VonC Please read the text at the bottom of the image.

Comment: @VonC unless you mean the src that is linked in the head tag of the site. Those files are bundled into the `bundle.js` file.

Comment: Did you specify the branch you want to use? https://github.com/blog/2228-simpler-github-pages-publishing

Comment: @VonC Yip, either way, both branches should work. I just don't have the source files in the gh-pages branch.